# How do I make a div top to be the bottom of other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I make a div top to be the bottom of other div like this:

[image]

I selected with firebug the div that I need the top to be always the bottom of

```
<div class="menu-banner">
```

What CSS would do the trick, or I need to use jQuery for this?

The target div and teh menu-banner div are both direct child of body. And that target is not child of menu-banner.

Comment: please post some of your code so that better help could be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply adding a `padding-top` with value `15%`

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` is breaking it for you. Your requested alignment is default for `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need jQuery for this, you can solve this purely in CSS. The uppermost banner, the navigation bar and the image should all be relative to a parent container (it can just be the body element or you can have a container div).

I know this is not exactly what you are asking, but you might consider using a framework such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) in order to help you with common layouts like the one you seem to be using.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand you correctly, you may want to put a child box in the bottom of its parent, if so:
You can consider `position: relative` to the parent box and `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to the child.

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q03mL0c/)